# XAMPP INSTALL COMPLETE WITH ERROR MESSAGE

Tags: xampp

I got "Ports 80 or 443(SSL) already in use! Installing Apache2.2 service failed" and "Port 3306 already in use! Installing Mysql service failed" messages while installing xampp 1.7.7 in Windows7. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

this error comes because specified port would being used by some other service. Going there and stopping those service will solve your problem

Go to run Command and check the service MySQL that will be running already beacuse of that 3306 port being used, just stop that service by right clicking. Similarly check for Apache Tomcat or Oracle which uses the 80 port, stop that service and then try to start service from Xamp. It will work